# Laravel HasOne relationship empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a relationship between Player and Roleplay and its returning null. I know for a fact it should be working because the following code works perfectly:

```
Roleplay::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

And returns the correct data, a full array of the correct data.

When trying to access it this way:

```
Auth::user()->roleplay->user_id;
```

It doesn't work, can someone help me find out why? 
**How do you know its empty?**

Because `{{var_dump(Auth::user()->roleplay)}}` in blade view returns `EMPTY`

When using it the view I also get a undefined error.
Primary key of roleplay table (srp_user_statistics) is user_id, and the primary key of player table (users) is id

here is the code:

```
Player:
<?php
namespace App\Database\Frontend\User;

use Hash;
use Eloquent;
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authentication;

class Player extends Eloquent implements Authentication
{
    use Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
    protected $table        = 'users';
    public $timestamps      = false;
    protected $fillable     = [];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['username'] = $value;
    }

    public function roleplay()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Frontend\User\Roleplay', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Roleplay:

```
use Eloquent;

class Roleplay extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'user_id';
    protected $table        = 'srp_user_statistics';
    public $timestamps      = true;
    protected $fillable     = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Frontend\User\Player', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function government_role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Frontend\Roleplay\GovernmentRole', 'government_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `Auth::user()` result?

Comment: Auth::user() is perfectly fine. I am display my username with it and it displays perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you should add 'id' to hasOne() in the User model

```
public function roleplay()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Frontend\User\Roleplay', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

And remove 'id' from belonsTo() in Roleplay model.

**Side notes**

This working

```
Roleplay::find(Auth::user()->id);
```

Is not a guarantee your relationships are set properly. All it does is

```
Roleplay::find(1); //$user->id returns an integer.
```

Comment: The primary key IS user_id, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It's still null, this hasn't fixed anything.

Comment: @Beefo the second argument of belongsTo method must be the foreign key, if you want to custom your parent model primary key, you can pass a third argument to belongsTo method.

Comment: Oh I think I get what you mean now. Maybe because the foreign key is also the primary key?

Comment: The primary key of class 'Roleplay' is user_id and the primary key of class 'Player' is ID, if that helps clear things up.

Comment: OK I see. In your User model, in the relationship, add 'id' as the third argument. You should be good to go. `return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Frontend\User\Roleplay', 'user_id', 'id');`

Comment: I have done that, do I keep the Roleplay one as 'return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Frontend\User\Player', 'user_id', 'id');' ?? It's returning null still but just checking I have them both right?

Comment: In Roleplay you dont need to add 'id' in the relationship. YOu can remove it from there. But add in User. That's how I have been doing it in L5.4 and it's working.

Comment: @gentcys No it isn't, I am not sure why.. I am simply trying to select a record from srp_user_statistics where column user_id equals to users table column id's value, but its just returning null.

Comment: I struggle to understand your design how your primary key 'user_id' is also your foreign key. Can you explain why you don't have a primary key and a separate key different?

Comment: Okay so I'll explain in depth as much as I can on this comment. class 'Player' is a model for MySQL table 'users', the 'Roleplay' class is a model for MySQL table 'srp_user_statistics'. The primary key for table 'users' is 'id', and the primary key for 'srp_user_statistics' is 'user_id'. I am trying to GET a record in srp_user_statistics' WHERE srp_user_statistics.user_id = user.id, if you're from a mysql background something like this: "SELECT `column`,`column`,`column` FROM srp_user_statistics WHERE user_id = '" . Auth::user()->id . "'"

Comment: Although you did not explain why you 'user_id' is your foreign key for user AND the primary key for Roleplay, what you are trying to is like this `$roleplay = Roleplay::find(Auth::user()->id);`. That one works fine you said. Now, in your relationship, your foreign key 'user_id' IS ALSO the primary key for Roleyplay. Why?

Comment: Column user_id is a primary key of table srp_user_statistics so that there aren't multiple records for the same user id inserted.